# mongoDB group documents after unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my mongodb `books` collection I have documents that look like:

```json
    {
      _id: ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea51),
      contributors:[ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea52), ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea53)]
      //other fields
    }
```

And I want to do a query that returns me documents like:

```json
    {
      _id: ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea51),
      contributors:[
                     {
                       _id: ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea52),
                       first_name: 'Luigi'
                       //many other fields
                     },
                     {
                       _id: ObjectId(625efa44f1ba751c8275ea53),
                       first_name: 'Mario'
                       //many other fields
                     },
                   ]
      //other fields
    }
```

I did an `unwind` on contributors and a `lookup` with my `users` collection and now I need to group them. I haven't used it before but I did something like:

```js
    {
        $group:{
                 _id: '_id'
               }
    }
```

But I don't know what to do next in order to preserve all the fields from books and also from users.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `$lookup` result is small enough (<16MB [document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit)),
you can simply do a `$lookup`.

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "contributors",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "contributors"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RYRkINvcQaJ) for your reference.

If the `$lookup` result will exceed 16 MB limit, you can still `$unwind. Just use` $first`to regroup the other fields after the`$unwind`

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "contributors",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "contributors"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$contributors"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "_id",
      bookName: {
        $first: "$bookName"
      },
      "contributors": {
        "$push": "$contributors"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SUlYKya0oWH) for your reference.

Comment: for the first case, has the entire lookup result to be smaller than 16MB or each resulting document?

Comment: @Loudrous yes you are right. You can workaround it with [$lookup + $unwind coalesce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence) optimization if needed.